# Conversion of html string to pdf in angular results distorted page in downloaded pdf using jsPDF

Tags: javascript, angular, jspdf, html2canvas

I am getting a html page's complete code as a string in an api response. I need to convert it to PDF.

I have tried using jsPDF.i successfully converted the page but the page i not exactly same as its html view. The design is distorted. i have given reference to the expected image and what i am getting below.
[image: expected image] [image: the result]

> the funtion in which the conversion code is written .

```js
 getHtmlForPdf(id, name) {
    this.appService
      .GET('Order/details?OrderId=' + id + '&ReportName=' + name)
      .subscribe((response) => {
        // console.log(response?.result.html_ContentForPdf);
        this.htmlData = response?.result.html_ContentForPdf
      });

        // this.saveAsPdf(response.result.html_ContentForPdf);
        const options = {
          background: 'white',
          scale: 3
        };
        html2canvas(this.htmlData, options)
          .then((canvas) => {
            var img = canvas.toDataURL('image/PNG');
            var doc = new jsPDF('l', 'mm', 'a4');

            // Add image Canvas to PDF
            const bufferX = 5;
            const bufferY = 5;
            const imgProps = (<any>doc).getImageProperties(img);
            const pdfWidth = doc.internal.pageSize.getWidth() - 2 * bufferX;
            const pdfHeight = (imgProps.height * pdfWidth) / imgProps.width;
            doc.addImage(
              img,
              'PNG',
              bufferX,
              bufferY,
              pdfWidth,
              pdfHeight,
              undefined,
              'FAST'
            );

            return doc;
          })
          .then((doc) => {
            doc.save('postres.pdf');
          });
  }
```

I have tried without using html canvas also.still not working

```js
 saveAsPdf(data) {
    window['html2canvas'] = html2canvas;
    var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');
    doc.html(data, {
      callback: function (pdf) {
        pdf.save('cv-a4.pdf');
      },
    });
  }
```

I found many solution for converting html file to pdf. But in my case i am converting the html code  as a string to pdf file. Please give me a solution what I am missing.